# Get matrix column name by matching vector

Tags: r

I started with a matrix

```
    Xray              Stay              Leave
[1,] "H"              "H"               "H"           
[2,] "A"              "L"               "O"
```

And I have the following vector:

```
[1] "H" "L"
```

I want to get the output

```
"Stay".
```

I tried this:

```
             which(vec %in% matrix )
```

but that gives me the following output:

```
[1] 1 2
```

Seems to be just telling me the rows that it finds the H and L in. I need the column name of the one that is an exact match.

Comment: Does the order of `vec` matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `m` is your matrix, you could do

```
> vec <- c("H", "A")
> colnames(m)[apply(m, 2, identical, vec)]
```

NOTE: `identical` used here because the original post says *"I need the column name of the one that is an **exact** match"*

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
vec <- c("H", "L")
colnames(mat)[colMeans(mat == vec) == 1]
# [1] "Stay"
```

where `mat` is the name of your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This should return a logical vector:

```
 logv <-     apply(mat, 2, function(x) identical(vec,x))
```

Then this will select the correct column name:

```
 dimnames(mat)[[2]][logv]
 [1] "Stay"
```

Test case:

```
mat <- matrix( c( "H","H", "H", "A","L","O") ,2, byrow=TRUE, 
               dimnames=list(NULL, c('Xray',    'Stay', 'Leave') ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:
    If `mat` and `vec` are the matrix and vector

```
colnames(mat)[table(mat %in% vec, (seq_along(mat)-1)%/%nrow(mat) +1)[2,] >1]
#[1] "Stay"
```